# Number of simple roots sent to negative roots by element of Weyl group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Given a root system $\Phi$ and a Weyl group $W$ associated with $\Phi$, it is well-known that the number of positive roots sent to negative roots by an arbitrary element $w \in W$ is equal to the length of $w$ (regardless of how we pick the positive roots).

Is there a similarly nice expression for the number of *simple roots* sent to negative roots by $w$?

I am interested in both the finite case as well as the affine case.

Comment: This number is $0$ iff $w=id$; it is $rank(\Phi)$ iff $w=$ longest element of $W$; and it's something strictly in between otherwise. This "something" might be interesting for some purposes, but e.g. for *all root systems of rank $2$*, it is necessarily $1$, which shows that you lose quite a bit of information.